# PHP scope between two classes

Tags: php, class, scope

I have a few files like below:

index.php:

```
require_once("foo.php");
require_once("bar.php");
```

foo.php:

```
class foo {

   function1() {

   }

}
```

bar.php:

```
class bar {

   ?????

}
```

My question is, is there any way of accessing function1 from the foo class in the bar class, without having to include the foo.php file in the bar.php file, as it has already been loaded in index.php?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Access how. Statically? Or access an object of that class?

Answer (score 1):

When including a file, in PHP, you are not including anything into the *current file*, but into the *current execution*

Once a file has been included, it's content is *known* by the PHP interpreter -- and will remain *known* until the end of the execution of the current script.

It's a bit like copy-pasting : with your current `index.php` file, it's like if you had taken the code from `foo.php` and `bar.php` and copy-pasted into `index.php`.

So, yes, once `foo.php` has been loaded once, you can access what's defined by it from `bar.php` -- even if those two are included by `index.php`.

(What you means by *access* is a bit vague, though : you'll have to declare some methods as static, or instanciate the `foo` class, ... But all that will be possible from inside the body on a method declared in `bar`)

As a sidenote : you should be careful with your file inclusions : if you include twice a file that declares a class, for example, you'll get a fatal error, because it's forbidden to define two classes with the same name.

Remember the copy-pasting idea I wrote about earlier ? Includind a file twice, even from two distinct files, is like copy-pasting the same code twice...

To avoid that problem, we often use [**`include_once`**](http://fr.php.net/include_once) which, as its name indicates, makes sure that a given file can only be included only once.

Answer (score 1):

If `foo.php` has already been loaded, then the real question to ask yourself is, "Am I accessing `function1()` in a static or instance manner?"

If `function1()` is a static function (which in your example, is not):

```
class bar{

  function function2(){
    return foo::function1();
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to instantiate an instance of `foo`, making it a local- or class-scope variable, e.g.

```
class bar{

  /*
   * @var foo
   */
  private $foo;

  function __construct(){
    $this->foo = new foo();
  }

  function function2(){
    return $this->foo->function1();
  }

}
```

Read this too: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

By the way, like what Pascal MARTIN has explained, you do not need to do another `include()`, but usually for a large application, you will prefer [auto-class-loading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to move away from including files manually, and instead work towards a solution where you can use autoloading.

Autoloading will allow you to lazy load, or only load the files that you need in each request - rather than making a spider web of included files.

You can do this either with __autoload or spl_autoload, read more on the subject here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Small example of autoload below:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once $class_name . '.php';
}

$obj  = new MyClass1();
$obj2 = new MyClass2();
```

Using autoloading php can automatically try to load files when a class is not found, in this example there is no reason to include the class files for MyClass1 or MyClass2, php falls back to the __autoload function if it cannot find definitions for them.

Using this will mean you dont have to include either foo or bar in your examples, nor include them in index.php

Answer (score 0):

You could do it statically, though there are limitations and this is an atrocious practice, since that function isn't actually static.

```
foo::function1();
```

The better approach would be to have the class bar take foo as a parameter.  Depending on the uses, this could be done in the constructor or the particular method.